# Passing more then one variable to another page using form action

Tags: php, html

This code works:

```
 <td><form method="post" action="DisplayBrand.php?name=<?php echo $_Post['Brand']?>">
```

But I want to send another value to the php page. I want it to be Flag=Brand (the word brand). I've tried

```
  <td><form method="post" action="DisplayBrand.php?name=<?php echo $_Post['Brand']?>&name=BrandName">
```

but it doesn't show on the other page. I've been able to send more then one variable from just a link, but I'm having trouble as part of the form action statement.

Comment: you cant use name twice, simply rename the 2nd name

Comment: I meant to say Flag. Sorry. I called it Flag=BrandName. I need more coffee.

Comment: why don't you use a URL instead?, anyway you need to validate all the information submitted by the client (it doesn't matter if it's post or get)

Answer (score 0):

Form and/or query string values are just key/value pairs.  The thing to note in your example is the *key* for each value:

```
DisplayBrand.php?name=<?php echo $_Post['Brand']?>&name=BrandName
```

Notice that both keys are called `name`.  Thus, how would the resulting server-side code be able to discern between them when using this?:

```
$_GET['name']
```

To send two separate values, you need two separate keys.  Without further context I wouldn't really know what to call your new key, but any unique key will do:

```
DisplayBrand.php?name=<?php echo $_Post['Brand']?>&nametype=BrandName
```

Now the values can be discerned:

```
$_GET['name']
$_GET['nametype']
```

Comment: I did that and it does have an unique name and it still is blank.

Comment: @user2900988: Can you provide some updated information?  What is the URL (with query string values), and how are you getting the values server-side?  What is the sequence of events in the request/response with the server?  (That is, in your Net tab in any browser debugger, what do the requests and responses look like?  Is a redirect getting in the way or something?)  Also, why are these query string values instead of form values?  It seems like a more consistent approach would be to include them in the form.

Comment: I'm getting the values from a dynamic drop down list and that's why its a query string value:

Comment: @user2900988: That doesn't really explain why it needs to be a query string.  If the values are populated from the `change` event of a `select` element then I imagine it would be a lot easier to populate separate form elements than to parse values into a string on the `action` attribute.  In any event, that description is only further clouding the bigger picture of what is happening in your code.  I suspect there's an assumption being made somewhere in your implementation which isn't valid, but isn't shown in the limited information provided.

Comment: I'm using an Option Select and getting the values from a mysql database. I'm sorry I'm not doing a good job explaining. I really do appreciate your help. Populating separate form elements may be the way to go. I just thought since it worked with a link, it could work in a form action statement too.